# I have recently updated my android studio and it is giving 2 errors while creating new project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

i am new to android studio.I was trying to import a project but I couldn't so I decided to create a new project ,but i am receiving these two errors.(I had successfully created and tested some projects before this new update)

```
C:\Users\Liar One\AndroidStudioProjects\Fragments_3\app\build.gradle

Error:Failed to resolve: javax.inject:javax.inject:1

Error:Failed to resolve: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1
```

I read some answers here about similar problems like using VPNs to let android studio gradle, download dependencies but they couldn't help

here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.liarone.fragments_3"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild project.

Comment: Please add your build.gradle files to your question

Comment: @larsgrefer  ok I will add them

Comment: @AbhriyaRoy it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here's what my friend told me to do and it worked for me.

First try to remove these 2 lines in build.gradle(Module:app)

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here is how my file looks like.

```
dependencies {

   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   // androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
     //   exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    //})
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
   // testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Then in java directory, i removed these two java files

"ExampleInstrumentedTest" and "ExampleUnitTest"

And I tested my app on my android device.I don't know if there will be critical issues later so if u know what I am missing here tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to first try to build you project through command line

```
./gradlew clean build
```

If you have gradle install with env variable set to its classpath.

```
./gradle clean build
```

If the problem persist then the issue is with you dependencies configuration not Android studio.

**Edit**
Add these dependencies which your project is not able to resolve.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject
compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup/javawriter
compile group: 'com.squareup', name: 'javawriter', version: '2.1.1'
```

Comment: so if the issue is with my dependencies configuration what is the solution?

Comment: Google up the files which your build is not able to resolve and try to find out which dependency is needed for the same. Then add them up in your dependeny tag.

Comment: Sachin sorry I didn't understand your comment.Will you plz explain more or send me a link about what you mentioned.

Comment: Sachin I did what u said.(copied them and added them in my build.gradle) i still have the same errors in log.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your dependency

```
    compile 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1'
compile 'javax.inject'
```

And in your project level build.gradle add

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
       maven {
            url "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject"
 }
}
}
```

This should solve it.

Comment: C:\Users\Liar One\AndroidStudioProjects\Fragments_3\app\build.gradle
Error:(25, 0) Supplied String module notation 'javax.inject' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.

Comment: remove the compile 'javax.inject' line from your dependency and try